# Adding numbers to arrays with methods in another class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I am learning java and trying to figure out how to implement these methods into my main class from a second class. The program takes user input to add numbers into an array and then I need to print the following using the pre-specified methods below. The parameters in the below method is what confuses me.

```
 public static double findMin(double[] numbers, int count) //count is the count of numbers        stored in the array

 public static double computePositiveSum(double[] numbers, int count)

 public static int countNegative(double[] numbers, int count)
```

Basically, I am confused as to how I link all the variables and array between the two classes so they can recognize the parameters and return the correct value to output min, sum and number of negatives. Do I want the array in the main method?

---

Basically, what I did now to fix it was that I created the variables in the main method and then pass the variables in the main method through the parameters of the object I created that links to the secondary class. Does that seem ok?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you need to pass `count` as an argument instead of using `numbers.length` inside those functions?

Comment: Do you understand parameters in general? Do you *have* the appropriate variables in your calling class? Just pass those as arguments to the method...

Comment: Array's size is immutable in Java, and all method calls are pass by value of a reference, so you can't instantiate new array in a method, assign it to an argument and expect that the caller sees the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the array , so what you need is call your methods and pass this value to it

lets say you have this array :

```
 double[] num = {1.2,2.3};
```

and your `count` is the length of `num` array , so the count is:

```
  int count = num.length;
```

then call your method and pass the parameters to it like this:

```
findMin(num , count );
computePositiveSum(num , count );
countNegative(num , count );
```

---

Note : you need to read in [Object-Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys for such a question. I just needed a refresher since it has been awhile. I resolved the issue by creating the array and count variable in the main method and then passed those through the parameters so the methods in the secondary class could read them. Thanks for the quick responses and help .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a count variable, you can use `myarray.length`
So your code should be something like this:

```
public static void main(string [] args)
{
    double[] myarray = {5.3, 69.365, 125, 2.36};

    double result = MyClass.findMin(myarray);

}

public class MyClass
{
    public static double findMin(double[] numbers) 
    {
        // your impl
    }

    public static double computePositiveSum(double[] numbers)
    {
        // your impl
    }

    public static int countNegative(double[] numbers)
    {
        // your impl
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an object reference of the main class in your derived class. Then call these methods using the object of your main class.

```
class Main
{
  ------
} 

class derived
{
  Main m = new Main();double[] A=new double[1];
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0,wc=1;
    int arrayGrowth=1;
    while(s.hasNext())
    {
      if (A.length == wc) {
                // expand list
                A = Arrays.copyOf(A, A.length + arrayGrowth);
                wc+=arrayGrowth;
               }
    A[i]=s.nextDouble();
    i++;
    }
    int len=A.length-1;
  m.findMin(A,len);
  m.computePositiveSum(A,len);
  m.countNegative(A,len);
}
```